# is it possible to confine an atom in a container

Tags: atomic-physics

Is it possible to confine an atom in a container for an indeterminate period of time?
A possibly better way of phrasing the question: is it possible to block an atom from passing through an object?

Comment: If you fill a glass with water, won't all the water molecules stay inside?

Comment: Atoms might not do it very often, but an atom can slip through a container.    What I'm less clear on is whether a water molecule would stay intact, I'm guessing it wouldn't, but some very very small percentage of the content inside would probably escape.   I think that's part of the uncertainty principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

Watch about 20 minutes into this video:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x20rn7s_nova-the-ghost-particle-discovery-science-universe-documentary_tv

they discuss early neutrino detection methods in the mid-1960's whereby the scientists somehow isolated, from a giant tank filled with 600 tones of cleaning fluid, only THREE Argon atoms per week--the extremely rare neutrino collision with a Chlorine atom produced a radioactive Argon atom.

They found and removed the three atoms and transported them across the country in a "tube" to a lab to be counted.

So, yes, it is possible to confine an atom in a container

Comment: thanks i just wanted to know if it was possible so you answer was a lot of help